# Custom font on Windows 8.1 Universal

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, ui-design

I want to use a custom font on Windows 8.1 universal app.
I search a little to understand how can I do that. I do that in this way:
1) import ttf font to my app.
2) set build action to Content.
3) use that in my control: `FontFamily="/Fonts/meteocons.ttf#Meteocons"`
But this is not work for me!
Is it possible to help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Valid schema for FontFamily looks like:

FontFamily="FONT_FILE_PATH#FONT_NAME"

FONT_NAME is real name of font (you can find it, in font previewer)

Check if you have a valid path and name(maybe you have some unnecessary slashes or not full path), because it should works, and it works very well for me.

```
<TextBlock Text="CustomFontem" FontFamily="Assets/Garfield.ttf#Garfield Hates Mondays Loves Fonts" FontSize="64"/>
```

You can also change font file **Copy To Output Directory** option to **Copy always**.

Comment: thanks. I find problem. I download some font and they have Font Name with ad so I change them with a program. They are work great in Office word an other program with their new name But when I use them in VS, they don't work. When I use real name of them, my problem solved.